# Search random in Mongodb and Meteor.js

Tags: mongodb, search, meteor

How can I do a random search in Mongodb and Meteor.js, so that the results do not always go in the same order?

Comment: What do you mean by random search? is that you want different search result or just different order of the same result?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash shuffle](https://lodash.com/docs#shuffle) like:

```
_.shuffle(CollectionName.find().fetch())
```